# What's the easiest solution to get digitalized representation of the text on an image?

Tags: image-processing

Assume the image is only in black and white.

Is there a software that can generate a matrix representation for the text on the image?

Comment: What you want is really not clear at all. Elaboration/example?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)-Software.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to an image like the one below, then it's pretty straight forward.

[image]

You just do the following:

- Read the image into a 2D byte array so you can access the pixels
- Loop through the array and look for every black pixel (0)
- Store these in a matrix however you need to

This assumes that lettering is pure black on white, you might have to allow values upto a certain value (5 or 10) if this isn't the case.

Comment: It depends of what is needed, if each character is needed, then it is a little bit more complex than this approach.
And text angle also is important